# how to use bootstrap thumnails with video?

Tags: video, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

i use bootstrap thumbnails. But i want to add video element not image.But i can't

### My code is:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="span4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <video data-src="holder.js/300x200" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOaOjN-rsIM">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                <hr>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li></ul>
```

Comment: Why can't you? Please elaborate…

Comment: check this snippet http://bootsnipp.com/abudayah/snippets/6Knvr

Answer (score 4):

Try using an iframe with youtube embed code as the source.  I'm assuming that you also would want this to be responsive as well so I've added the div with the "flex-video" class as well.  Here is a link to a [Bootply Project](http://www.bootply.com/115837) that should help you if you need.

HTML :

```
        <ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="span4">
            <div class="thumbnail">


                <div class="flex-video widescreen ">
                  <iframe class="" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/8wqtwkmsBvc" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>   


              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
```

CSS (for responsive video):

```
         .flex-video {
          position: relative;
          padding-top: 25px;
          padding-bottom: 67.5%;
          height: 0;
          margin-bottom: 16px;
          overflow: hidden;
           }

          .flex-video.widescreen { padding-bottom: 57.25%; }
          .flex-video.vimeo { padding-top: 0; }

          .flex-video iframe,
          .flex-video object,
          .flex-video embed {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
          }

 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px),  
 only screen and (device-width:1024px) and (device-height: 600px), only screen 

 and (width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape), only screen 

 and (device-width: 800px), only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

 .flex-video { padding-top: 0; }
   }
```